# What does the word "a**holes" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was reading a conversation on Facebook where some one said that "many girls like assholes". I tried to google it, but I couldn't get the exact meaning of the word. Who are assholes in this sentence? and does the word have other meanings?

Is it a slang?

Comment: Can't you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @Dangph , Sadly , I have lost my dictionary a couple of days ago. I'm going to buy a new one soon.

Comment: Never fear; there are many dictionaries on the internet. [Here](http://www.onelook.com/?w=asshole&ls=a) you may input a word and see links to the definitions in many dictionaries.

Comment: I initially voted to close this question as a simple dictionary lookup, but, after thinking about it some more, I think this part of the question makes it worth keeping open: "Who are _assholes_ in this sentence?" One could look the word up in the dictionary, and wonder if the sentence refered to anatomy instead of archtypes, since both meanings are likely to be co-listed, and both could be used in the grammatical sense.

Comment: Please include a link to the context--it's hard to answer a question of "What does this word mean in this context" when we don't have that context available!

Comment: @Tiercelet , it was on Facebook so you can't watch the conversation as it doesn't appear for public. moreover , the conversation was in my native language , they were only using the word and one of them write this statement. it wasn't clear about what they were talking .

Comment: Even when it's on Facebook in another language, you can still provide that information in your question, e.g.: _I was on Facebook reading a conversation, and I saw someone write "many girls like assholes" – not in English, but that's what it translates to in English. That made me wonder about the word "assholes" in this context. Is it common slang? What does it mean?_ Something like that makes it easier to figure out why you're asking, and makes people less likely to say, "Why doesn't this fellow just look it up in a dictionary?"

Comment: @J.R. , Ok , I will do this next time, but this particular sentence was en english. they were mixing languages so they use Arabic and from time to time they use english , They used "a**holes" all the times without clarifying the meaning. I apologise fot not giving more information. Next time , I will make sure to add more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context where you've seen this remark, I assume the word is a synonym for [*jerk*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/jerk), which means:

> A foolish, rude, or contemptible person.

I'd guess that the conversation that you allude to was more or less talking about the ["bad boy" phenomenon](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=why%20girls%20like%20bad%20boys&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). As [one columnist wrote](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/relationships/10357878/Why-women-cant-resist-bad-boys.html):

> *I'm often questioned by men who tell me they are "nice guys" but feel ignored by women who, they say, "prefer to be treated like crap". While I don't agree that nice guys always finish last, I do understand that we women do make some damn silly dating decisions*.
>
> *Most of the men I know are kind, polite and adorable in practically every way, yet, **like many women, I have an illogical soft-spot for massive jerks**. There is something about bad boys that we find incredibly appealing, even though we often regret the experience afterwards*.

I can't say if this is reality, myth, or urban legend, but there is a lot of serious discussion on the topic. As for why it's true (or if it's true), that would be a question for [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) – but at least you now know what the phrase is talking about.

Comment: And to answer the last part of your question, yes, it's slang, and it's also considered _vulgar slang_ (and most dictionaries will label it as such).

Comment: In fact , yes the disscusion was about why do women are attracted to bad guys not to nice ones.. I know understand what the topic is talking about. thanx .

Answer (score 0):

“ asshole”

> Stupid and contemptible person.

Comment: If you are quoting from a dictionary (or other reference), please either say where you took the quotation from, or provide a link to the source.